# IKEv2 disconnects on native Mac OS VPN client after 8 minutes

Tags: mac, network, vpn

Somehow, exactly on 8 minutes, my VPN tunnel to our WatchGuard Firebox M270 disconnects. I'm on the same internet connection as some of my other colleagues that have no problem connecting to the other building with the native client. Only thing I seem to be able to find with Console is the following. I'm unable to find out what these error messages from `neagent` are. I've found similar questions around, without solutions that seem to work for me.

```
error   08:26:43.354821 +0200   neagent Failed to receive delete packet
error   08:26:43.354854 +0200   neagent Failed to generate Delete old IKE SA
default 08:26:43.356705 +0200   nesessionmanager    <NESMServer: 0x7fb55ad00160>: Request to uninstall session: NESMIKEv2VPNSession[my location:A0722441-3AB4-40B1-973C-B60BF70DE5FE]
default 08:26:43.356744 +0200   nesessionmanager    NESMIKEv2VPNSession[my location:A0722441-3AB4-40B1-973C-B60BF70DE5FE]: status changed to disconnecting
default 08:26:43.356824 +0200   nesessionmanager    NESMIKEv2VPNSession[my location:A0722441-3AB4-40B1-973C-B60BF70DE5FE]: Updated network agent (inactive)
```

Mac OS: 10.14.6 (18G95)

MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015)

Comment: just stumbled over this. Can confirm I have the issue too, no idea why...

Comment: FWIW, I've always had this issue untill recently when I reinstalled my Mac OS entirely. Now it's stable.